# Multiple global bibliographies and local bibliographies after each section for non-global entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to realize the following: A large document spanning multiple sections with

- bibliographies after each section
- several academic profiles at the end, each including a list of own publications

but with the following (annoying) rule:

- if an author is included in the academic profiles at the end, then any citation of their work must refer to the respective list of publications in their academic profile.

Bibliographies after each section can be comfortably done using refsections. But what would be the easiest way to make the citation of some publications refer to the respective list of own publications at the very end?

I know that one possibility is to manually keep track where a reference should appear by using keywords. But is there any easier solution?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@misc{notMyWorkA,
    author = {Not Me},
    title  = {Something relevant A},
    year   = {2015},
}
@misc{notMyWorkB,
    author = {Not Me},
    title  = {Something relevant B},
    year   = {2016},
}
@misc{myWork,
    keywords = {byMyself},
    author = {My Self},
    title  = {Something relevant},
    year   = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\section{Example section}
Here is an example section including multiple citations like 
\cite{notMyWorkA}, \cite{notMyWorkB} and \cite{myWork}.

At the end of the section, there is a list of references. 
However, this list should not contain my own publications, 
which are supposed to be separately listed.

\subsection*{References}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=byMyself, heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\newpage
\begin{refsection}
\section{Academic profile of myself}

Here is an academic profile of myself including a description of my work, 
also with various citations such as \cite{notMyWorkA} and \cite{myWork}.

At the end, there is a list of references that appeared in this section. 
This list is supposed to distinguishes between publications of other people 
and that of my own. Any citation to my publications should refer to here.

\subsection*{References}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=byMyself, heading=none]

\subsection*{My publications}
\printbibliography[keyword=byMyself, heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There isn't an obvious answer to this as you have to somehow differentiate the entries which are printed in an "author profile" list. To generate that list in the first place, you have to already differentiate them (with some `\printbibliography` filter) - a circular problem. If the real criterion is that the work is by the author and not that it appears in the "author profile" list, then a hard-coded .bib entry filter like keywords is ok. You can potentially automate this with `\DeclareSourcemap`.

Comment: How should a reader find a bib-entry in this situation. Do you plan an instruction "look for [XYZ15] first at the end of the section, and if you can't find it there go throught the author profiles"? Who invented this silly rule?

Comment: We are using custom labels for citations that are listed in the author's profile. But yes, I am not a big fan of this DFG rule myself.