# Page header with references at end of each chapter

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, double-sided

I am using the `scrreprt` class and I am trying to modify the page header in my document.

I am generating a `twosided` document; chapters start on even pages. On even pages (except first page of chapter), the page header shall display the chapter title and the page number; on odd pages, the page header shall display the section title and the page number.

I have implemented these requirements in my document.

However, there is one situation with which I am not satisfied yet. I am generating a bibliography at the end of each chapter. For odd pages, the page headers behave just as I want them to, showing the "Section Title". However, if a bibliography starts on an even page, the page header says "References" instead of "Chapter Title".

I would like this to be fixed: "References" shall only appear in the page header on the succeeding pages (after the first) of the bibliography.
It seems as if every bibliography is treated as a chapter of its own. How can I work on this?

Please note that I want to stick to the KOMA-class `scrreprt`.

EDIT: I changed the code according to the suggestions (using refsegment instead of refsection). This is my second edit.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, chapterprefix, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=15pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=off]{scrlayer-scrpage} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Trennregeln
\usepackage{lmodern}    % fixes bug with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}; ändert Schriftart zudem in Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % für europäische Autoren ratsam; % wichtig für Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{patchcmd}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}           
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true,  linktoc=all,    
    %linkcolor=beierblau, 
    citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, breaklinks=false,
    bookmarksopen=true, colorlinks, linkcolor = black}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}        % needed to help hyperlinks direct correctly;
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}


%%%% Change Chapter Prefix
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge} % Default is \LARGE

%%% No Spacing Between Chapter Title and Prefix
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter} % <--- Vary distance here (Thanks @esdd!)

%%% Subsubsections kursiv erscheinen lassen + Abstand zwischen Überschrift/Nummerierung
%\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily \bfseries \large }{\thesubsection}{1em}{}   % auch NUmmerierung kursiv
%\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\sffamily \Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 0pt\raggedright}   %\vskip 20pt\raggedright


%%% Page header: No Dot after Numbering & Spacing between Numbering and Title in page headers
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter \quad}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\thesection \quad}

\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}

%%% PAGER HEADERS
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{plain.scrheadings}   % default=empty

\lehead{\pagemark}  % left even head
\rehead{\headmark}  % right even head   %leftmark = chapter

\lohead{\rightmark} % left odd head     %rightmark = section
\rohead{\pagemark}  % right odd head


%%% References
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,
refsegment=chapter % benutze automatisch Kapitel als Biobliographie-Abschnitte...
]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,labeldate=true,uniquelist=minyear}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Giancoli,
        Author    = {Douglas C. Giancoli},
        Publisher = {Pearson},
        Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
        Year      = {2014},
        Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}

%%% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}


\chapter{Test-Kapitel}
    \lipsum

\section{Test-Section}
    \lipsum
Some \cite{Giancoli} text \autocite{Giancoli}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum 

%\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibintoc, title={Literatur}]  
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe This sounds familiar. This is the same behaviour as mentioned in [the issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627#issuecomment-331504484). `biblatex` sets the mark, even if it is unwanted. :-) I should look at the KOMA addchap stuff.

Comment: Does `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` do what you want in all situations?

Comment: refsection=chapter seems like a bad idea.

Comment: John is right that if you use `refsection=chapter`, there is *probably* little point in calling `\printbibliography` with `segment=\therefsegment`. He is also right that in a single work you probably don't want to use `refsections`, you *probably* want `refsegments`. Do you want independent bibliographies per chapter, or do you want them to be connected (see http://golatex.de/mehrere-lit-verz-getrennt-nach-dokumentenbereiche-t19752.html)?

Comment: @Johannes_B I commend your precognition. ;-) The problem here could even be made worse by using `titlesec` with KOMA. But again, a KOMA expert would need to tell me how to set up the headings correctly. I am coming to the conclusion that we probably need to change some of the KOMA defaults in `biblatex`, but I'm still not sure if we can make everybody happy in the end.

Comment: @Johannes_B @moewe: Thanks for your advice. I was not aware of the difference between `refsegments` and `refsection`. Indeed, `refsegments` is better for my purposes. I tweaked the links of each refsegment to be local as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303503/hyperref-inside-refsegment-always-linking-to-first-bibliography-not-current-bib). However, my initial problem still remains. I tried `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` but it did not give me the desired result; also, it removed my pdfbookmark entries of the chapter bibliographies (not wanted).

Comment: Well, `titlesec` definitely messes with the bookmarks set by `\addsec`. This has nothing to do with `biblatex` and is just another indicator that you should drop `titlesec` as the warning message in the `.log` suggests. With `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` I get 'Test-Kapitel' on even pages and 'Literatur' on odd pages. I thought that is what you wanted?

Comment: Note that the fact that 'Literatur' appears on the first page of the bibliography if it is an odd page is consistent with how other sections are treated. There definitely is a difference between `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` and the standard settings on even pages in your set-up.

Comment: @moewe: So for test purposes, I ommited `titlesec`. Then I added `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` right before the line `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]`. What then happens, is that the bibliographies are forced to start on odd pages. This is not really what I need: For pages on which a bibliography begins, I want the page headers to show the chapter title, or the section title, respectively. On the succeeding pages, I want the page headers to say "References" until the end of the current bibliography. I also want "References" to appear in the pdfbookmarks.

Comment: Hang on. In your MWE you have `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibintoc, title={Literatur}]` that is crucially different from `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]` in that `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` is actually takes effect then. Note also that ideally `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}` goes into the preamble and not the text (although it is possible).

Comment: @moewe: I added my edited code in the initial question. Is this how you suggested?

Comment: @moewe. Ahh I got it working now. See my final edited code in a few seconds. Thank you.

Comment: Don't include the solution in your question. I have posted an answer with my suggested solution. If it helped you, accept it an up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{\addsec{#1}}
```

Simply put the code into your preamble.

The default for `heading=subbibintoc` is

```
\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \addsec{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

and includes a `\markboth{#1}{#1}` that you don't want.

This is related to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627, where Johannes mentioned that the KOMA heading settings probably need an overhaul.

Note also that `titlesec` should not be used with the KOMA classes.

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look at http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=30371? I have no idea what is going on with all the `ibid` and `idem`  stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh crikey, that is a complicated one. The code in `biblatex-chicago` is really complicated and lengthy and can be a pain to modify. There is `\ifuniquework` to check for situations where one `labelname`-`labeltitle` combination occurs more than once, one could use that to add additional information. It is not clear to me, however, what the expected behaviour would be in that case. What would one add? Can we make sure that by adding that bit we get a unique citations? Etc.?

Comment: @Johannes_B Not really keen on signing up for another forum, but a first suggestion can be found at https://gist.github.com/moewew/9805f72a43ca2cc56ee6e4c3819a2354 This will issue a full citation if the short 'name-title' is not unique. For LyX users note that I had to add the loading option `uniquework=true` to `biblatex-chicago` (this is crucial), the other interesting bit is between the redefinition of `cite`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I added your remarks in a quote in a reply: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=30371&p=102706#p102706

Comment: @moewe: As you have mentioned, it is probably best to drop ´titelsec´. However, will I then still be able to (a) manipulate the distance between the numbering and the corresponding title in headings and (b) manipulate the spacing between chapter title and text on the first pages of a new chapter?

Comment: To achieve these requirements, I have the following code in my preamble: `\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily \bfseries \large }{\thesubsection}{1em}{}   % add "\itshape" für kursive Schreibweise
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\sffamily \Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 0pt\raggedright}   %\vskip 20pt\raggedright
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}`

Comment: @dan I have a strong hunch that that is possible, but it is not my expertise, so I can't help you much with that. Just ask a new question with a useful MWE and exact description of what you need about it and I'm sure people will be able to help you.